# Как инициализировать yandex map api 3:0 в реакт?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как инициализировать yandex map api 3:0 в реакт с дальнейшим использованием реакт компонент?
Документация сильно молчит по этому поводу, друзья помогите!

P.S.ушел с yandex map api на react-leaflet. С react-leaflet я в 10 раз сделал все задачи которые хотел

Comment: Насколько вижу, в документации говорится, что API не имеет зависимостей, не требует компиляции или подключения View-движка, а для React есть обертка, которая повторяет JavaScript API. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/dg/concepts/general.html#react При этом инициализация вызовом в head <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/3.0/?apikey=<ваш_API-ключ>&lang=ru_RU"></script> тоже описана. Что именно вам не нравится и что не получается? Может пример наработок хоть покажете?

Answer (score 0):

Вот [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/dlsuqq?initialpath=react.html&file=/react.html) с react, посмотрите.

Comment: тут понятно инициализация самого реакта через cdn сделана, а вот вопрос как через create-react-app установить yandex map api.

Answer (score 0):

вот самая простая реализация: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ymap3-components-xk3d74

```
import React from "react";
import {
  YMap,
  YMapDefaultSchemeLayer,
  YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer
  // ...other components
} from "ymapv3-components";
import { features, LOCATION } from './helpers'

function Map() {
  return (
    <YMapComponentsProvider apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_YMAP_KEY}>
      <YMap location={location}>
        <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer />
        <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer />
        <YMapDefaultMarker
          coordinates={LOCATION.coordinates}
        />
      </YMap>
    </YMapComponentsProvider>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

Но можно достать компоненты с помощью reactify

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)